# ASP.net: How to use bind() to select partial strings?

Tags: asp.net, substring, bind

I have this ...

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="lbWGyear" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Workgroup") %>' />
```

Where Workgroup is a field that returns a char(3) of values such as "S1", "S2", "S3", etc.

How can I write the above bind() function to return a single char from the above values such as "1" in "S1", or "2" in "S2"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the return string as `returnStr = returnStr.Substring(1);` in method `Bind("Workgroup")`.

Comment: ?? Sorry I am new to ASP.net. Could you give me a sample of how to do this? Should I be doing it in C# or in the ASPX itself?